# Merge sass and scss

Tags: support, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

The [scss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scss) tag should be merged with [sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sass). Some posters don't even know that there is an old and a new **sass** CSS syntax, so they keep tagging questions incorrectly. What do you think?

Comment: They are not identical things. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654447/whats-the-difference-between-scss-and-sass

Comment: By Sass two things are meant the same time. The `sass` CSS format (no semicolons), and the Sass in general which equals to this `sass` + `scss` formats. So referring it as Sass would be okay.

Comment: There is a problem here: Sass refers to both a format and a library. Deleting the `scss` tag doesn't solve that problem. We need to either find a new name for the sass format or we have one tag for 2 things, which shouldn't be a problem imo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[scss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scss) has been a synonym of [sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sass) for a *long* time. Attempting to tag a question [scss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scss) will simply result in the tag being changed to [sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sass) automatically. I'm not sure what merging them would achieve.